# PyQt: Global copy/paste actions for custom widgets

Tags: menu, pyqt, pyqt4, copy-paste, custom-widgets

I'm writing a tool which has a big custom text area widget and a lot of other text input widgets, etc. I'm currently working with adding copy/paste to my tool and got stuck on how to do this on a global level - i.e. I don't want to implement copy/paste locally in every widget that needs it. For Qt standard widgets it just works to use copy/paste with Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, but of course I have to implement it manually for my custom widgets.

But what about copy/paste actions in the menu bar? Do I have to connect them to every widget that exists in my program, or is there some better built in way to do this? I would prefer if I could just connect the menu actions to some global copy/paste handler that notifies the widget in focus automatically.

Comment: Why do you have to reimplement copy/paste? Surely your custom widgets are just subclasses of Qt text input widgets.

Comment: No, unfortunately my widget is an extended QAbstractScrollArea for performance reasons. I render the contents myself to be able to view extremely large data amounts. And this component doesn't support copy/paste as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic copy/paste functionality - for custom widgets, you will have to implement everything yourself. The [QClipboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html) class provides access to the system clipboard. Every application has a single clipboard object, which can be accessed via `QApplication.clipboard()` or `qApp.clipboard()`.

The standard Qt input widgets all define their own `copy()` and `paste()` slots that can be connected to menu actions, toolbar buttons, keyboard shortcuts, etc. So your custom widgets should probably define the same interface.

There are classes such as [QActionGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html), [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttonongroup.html), and [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) that provide support for centralised signal handling, but it is often much simpler to stick with explicit, one-to-one connections.